# Expose Spring Beans to a Micronaut Application

Tags: java, spring-boot, autowired, micronaut, spring-bean

Is it possible to Expose Spring Beans to a Micronaut Application and use them with @Autowired or @Inject them into the Micronaut Application with the Spring Beans project added as Maven Dependency to the Micronaut Project via Maven pom.xml?

The guide:
https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-spring/latest/guide/
Talks about "Expose Micronaut Beans to a Spring Application" but not vice versa.

The Spring Beans that I want to use in the Micronaut Application are exposed using @Repository, @Component, @Service, @Configuration.

Is this even possible and is it a pre-requisite to have the Spring Beans defined in the Micronaut Application itself and whether the use of a Library (a JAR file which has the Spring Beans defined) as a dependency to the Micronaut Application not supported?

Whenever I attempt to @Autowire or @Inject a Spring Bean defined in a different Application from a Micronaut Application (to which the former has been added as a dependency in pom.xml), I get the following Exception:

```
io.micronaut.context.exceptions.DependencyInjectionException: Failed to inject value for field [fieldName] of class: MicronautClassName_From_Where_I_have_Referrenced_the_Spring_Bean

Path Taken: Class.fieldName
    at io.micronaut.context.AbstractBeanDefinition.getBeanForField(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:1462)
    at io.micronaut.context.AbstractBeanDefinition.getBeanForField(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:1203)
    ...
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doCreateBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:1898)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.createAndRegisterSingletonInternal(DefaultBeanContext.java:2679)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.createAndRegisterSingleton(DefaultBeanContext.java:2665)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBeanForDefinition(DefaultBeanContext.java:2337)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.access$100(DefaultBeanContext.java:78)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext$4.getTarget(DefaultBeanContext.java:431)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext$4.invoke(DefaultBeanContext.java:474)
    at io.micronaut.web.router.AbstractRouteMatch.execute(AbstractRouteMatch.java:312)
    at io.micronaut.web.router.RouteMatch.execute(RouteMatch.java:118)
    at io.micronaut.http.server.netty.RoutingInBoundHandler.lambda$buildResultEmitter$10(RoutingInBoundHandler.java:1391)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableDefer.subscribeActual(FlowableDefer.java:35)
    at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14918)
    at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14868)
    at io.micronaut.core.async.publisher.Publishers.lambda$map$3(Publishers.java:196)
    at io.micronaut.http.server.context.ServerRequestContextFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(ServerRequestContextFilter.java:62)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFromPublisher.subscribeActual(FlowableFromPublisher.java:29)
    at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14918)
    at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14868)
    at io.micronaut.http.server.netty.RoutingInBoundHandler.lambda$buildExecutableRoute$6(RoutingInBoundHandler.java:1096)
    at io.micronaut.web.router.DefaultUriRouteMatch$1.execute(DefaultUriRouteMatch.java:80)
    at io.micronaut.web.router.RouteMatch.execute(RouteMatch.java:118)
    at io.micronaut.http.server.netty.RoutingInBoundHandler$2.doOnComplete(RoutingInBoundHandler.java:1022)
    at io.micronaut.core.async.subscriber.CompletionAwareSubscriber.onComplete(CompletionAwareSubscriber.java:71)
    at io.micronaut.http.server.netty.jackson.JsonContentProcessor$1.doOnComplete(JsonContentProcessor.java:140)
    at io.micronaut.core.async.subscriber.CompletionAwareSubscriber.onComplete(CompletionAwareSubscriber.java:71)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.ifPresent(Optional.java:183)
    at io.micronaut.core.async.processor.SingleThreadedBufferingProcessor.doOnComplete(SingleThreadedBufferingProcessor.java:48)
    at io.micronaut.jackson.parser.JacksonProcessor.doOnComplete(JacksonProcessor.java:137)
    at io.micronaut.core.async.subscriber.SingleThreadedBufferingSubscriber.onComplete(SingleThreadedBufferingSubscriber.java:70)
    at io.micronaut.http.server.netty.jackson.JsonContentProcessor.doOnComplete(JsonContentProcessor.java:165)
    at io.micronaut.core.async.subscriber.CompletionAwareSubscriber.onComplete(CompletionAwareSubscriber.java:71)
    at io.micronaut.http.netty.reactive.HandlerPublisher.complete(HandlerPublisher.java:416)
    at io.micronaut.http.netty.reactive.HandlerPublisher.handlerRemoved(HandlerPublisher.java:403)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.callHandlerRemoved(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:946)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.callHandlerRemoved0(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:637)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.remove(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:477)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.remove(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:423)
    at io.micronaut.http.netty.stream.HttpStreamsHandler.removeHandlerIfActive(HttpStreamsHandler.java:429)
    at io.micronaut.http.netty.stream.HttpStreamsHandler.handleReadHttpContent(HttpStreamsHandler.java:294)
    at io.micronaut.http.netty.stream.HttpStreamsHandler.channelRead(HttpStreamsHandler.java:257)
    at io.micronaut.http.netty.stream.HttpStreamsServerHandler.channelRead(HttpStreamsServerHandler.java:121)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageCodec.channelRead(MessageToMessageCodec.java:111)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelRead(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:93)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpServerKeepAliveHandler.channelRead(HttpServerKeepAliveHandler.java:64)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.handler.flow.FlowControlHandler.dequeue(FlowControlHandler.java:200)
    at io.netty.handler.flow.FlowControlHandler.read(FlowControlHandler.java:139)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:686)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.read(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:671)
    at io.micronaut.http.netty.reactive.HandlerPublisher.requestDemand(HandlerPublisher.java:163)
    at io.micronaut.http.netty.stream.HttpStreamsHandler$2.requestDemand(HttpStreamsHandler.java:248)
    at io.micronaut.http.netty.reactive.HandlerPublisher$ChannelSubscription.receivedDemand(HandlerPublisher.java:547)
    at io.micronaut.http.netty.reactive.HandlerPublisher$ChannelSubscription.lambda$request$0(HandlerPublisher.java:474)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:164)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:472)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:497)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
**Caused by: io.micronaut.context.exceptions.NoSuchBeanException: No bean of type [Bean_that_I_am_Trying_to_Autowire] exists. Make sure the bean is not disabled by bean requirements (enable trace logging for 'io.micronaut.context.condition' to check) and if the bean is enabled then ensure the class is declared a bean and annotation processing is enabled (for Java and Kotlin the 'micronaut-inject-java' dependency should be configured as an annotation processor).**
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBeanInternal(DefaultBeanContext.java:2322)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:1245)
    at io.micronaut.context.AbstractBeanDefinition.getBeanForField(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:1441)
    ... 76 common frames omitted
```

I have followed all the pre-requisites.